# error: invalid conversion from 'short unsigned int*' to 'short unsigned int'| (in c++)

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and I have been trying to create a program that would solve any Sudoku puzzle. However, I've been getting a lot of errors, and in this one I just can't figure out what's wrong.

This is the code where the error is:

```
for (short o = indice;o>=divergencias[n_diver];o--){
    N=historico[o];
    P=tabela[N];  //Line 205
    tabela[N]=0;  //Line 206
    }
    indice -= divergencias[n_diver];
    n_diver --;
    }
```

And the errors, which happened on the lines marked with comments, are:

```
C:\(...)\main.cpp|205|error: invalid conversion from 'short unsigned int*' to 'short unsigned int'|
```

and

```
C:\(...)\main.cpp|206|error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'short unsigned int [9]'|
```

I've been searching for this error, and didn't find any satisfying answer to it. Moreover, the website in which I learn what I know about programming specifies that writing something like `b = billy [a+2];` is valid. So I just can't understand what's wrong with this...

Comment: Where do you declare `tablea`? Is it a 2D array? Also please include declarations for your other variables.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you think lines 205 and 206 do? It looks like tabela is a 2D array (this is sudoku right). But those lines would only be correct if tabela was a 1D array.

Comment: Show the declarations of `N`, `tabela` and `P`. Somewhere here is a type mismatch.

Comment: Geesh... Sorry for wasting your time. Yes, tabela was a 2D array. I have replaced tabela[N] with tabela[N%9][N/9]
Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `tabela` is declared as `short unsigned tabela[9][9]`. In order to get an item of type `unsigned short` from it you have to provide two indexes, not one.

On the other hand, if you are looking to get an entire sub-array from `tabela`, the left side of the assignment needs to be compatible with a 1-D array of `unsigned short`, for example, an `unsigned short*` pointer.